# Emails headers with swiftmailer and Symfony 2

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I asked a similar question earlier, but the context has changed a bit. I want to use swiftmailer to send an email in Symfony 2. The problem is I'm using the gmail SMTP server, and so when my message arrives, my email client shows it from gmail.com, rather than mydomain.com. How can I fix this?

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Hello Email')
        ->setFrom(array('digest@mydomain.com' => "Digest"))
        ->setSender(array('digest@mydomain.com' => "Digest"))
        ->setCharset('iso-8859-1')
        ->setContentType('text/html')
        ->setTo('myemail@gmail.com')
        ->setBody($this->renderView('email.html.twig', array()));

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: If I'm correct, gmail don't allow sending emails with different domain than gmail. Restriction made to fight spammers I suppose. If you want someone to reply to other domain you could add `$message->setReplyTo('new.email@example.com')` and return path header: `$headers->addTextHeader('Return-Path', 'new.email@example.com');`

Comment: You cannot set `Return-Path`, it is the responsibility of the delivery agent to set this header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gmail SMTP server only allows you to send mail using the email address you're aithenticating with. So if you configured Symfony with

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_user: myemail@gmail.com
mailer_password: ******
```

All your messages we'll look like they're from `myemail@gmail.com`

What you can do maybe is use another smtp server that is more flexible in the types of From addresses they will allow. If you are on a local development server, you could use your ISP's SMTP server, or use one of the various email as a service provider, such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com) or [postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com)

They all allow you to send messages from any address you can prove ownership of, after some configuration steps.

One thing that may be worth trying also if you really want to use the gmail smtp server, is to define your from address in your "Send mail as" Gmail configuration (in Settings -> Accounts). This will let your app send email using the configured adresses in the `From:` field.

Comment: That answers it. Thanks dude.